# Only one cover letter allowed in job portal for multiple positions

Tags: job-search, cover-letter

I am applying for jobs and there is one portal powered by iRecruitment. The rules for the resume and cover letter are as follows

- The resume and cover letter in your profile are always the most recently uploaded versions.
- When you upload a new version, the old version will be removed.
- You cannot have different resumes or cover letters for different job applications
- To check if your resume or cover letter were uploaded, click on the blue link after you update your profile.

I can apply to multiple positions, but it only allows for one resume and one cover letter. Since I am qualified for these positions, would I need to write a general cover letter?

Comment: Why would you need more than one cover letter or resume? Shouldn't your cover letter and resume include all of the relevant and pertinent information, regardless of the job you're applying for?

Comment: @joeqwerty That might be true for the resume (just include all relevant information), but it's usually advised to tailor the cover letter to the job.

Comment: I am not familiar with IRecruitment and I assume it is some sort of jobsearch website (meaning the jobs are for different companies) but cant you just write a cover letter, upload, apply for a job, write new cover letter, upload, apply for other job? It is always better to send a more taillored cover letter. If the jobs are with the same comapny I agree with the answer already given.

Comment: @user180146 iRecruitment is a recruitment portal system that specific companies use. I cannot do what you suggested because the third bullet point states "you cannot have different resumes or cover letters for different job applications" and even if I try and upload a new cover letter, it will take the place of my previous cover letter, so I can't tailor the cover letter unless I only apply for one job at a time, hence my question.

Comment: @86BCP2432T So the jobs are with the same company? In that case, big or small I would apply for the most suited one.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick the most appropriate job. Write CV/Cover letter for that.

Any recruiter worth his/her salt will spot that you might be suitable for one of the other roles.

Also applying for multiple jobs at the same company makes you seem desperate.

Answer (score 1):

[Ed Heal's response](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/146059/85657) seems like a good option for a niche role in a small company that did not outsource headhunting.

But if we are talking about a big company who might receive thousands of applications for every role:

You might often have your CV read only by machines, selected only if it seems like a good fit, and then shown to a human. So, maybe the software used by HR thinks you are a good fit for one role but not another. If you can send different CVs to different job applications, then consider doing so.

Also, you can have a generic cover letter, or you can claim in the cover letter that you are applying both for positon A and position B. There is nothing wrong with that, as long as you are at least a reasonable fit for both. You'll only look desperate or piss off the recruiter if you are applying for a job that's a very poor match. Think of an electronic engineer with only PCD design experience applying for a software development role.